# Regular Expression Redirects / 301

Tags: apache, redirect

I am dealing with an interesting situation. Here's what's going on:

Current URLs Example1:

```
www.domain.com/red-widgets-cid-1234.html

www.domain.com/red-widgets-cid-1234-1.html

www.domain.com/red-widgets-cid-1234-1-1.html
```

Canonical on All Above URLs:

```
www.domain.com/red-widgets-cid-1234.html

New URL:
www.domain.com/red-widgets-cid-4567.html
```

---

Current URLs Example2:

```
www.domain.com/red-widgets-cid-1234+10.html

www.domain.com/red-widgets-cid-1234+10-1.html

www.domain.com/red-widgets-cid-1234+10-1-1.html
```

Canonical on All Above URLs:

```
www.domain.com/red-widgets-cid-1234+10.html

New URL:
www.domain.com/red-widgets-cid-6789.html
```

I want to make sure all variations of the above URL redirect to the new url. What wildcard 301 redirect / regular expression can I use to tackle these ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (haven't tested it):

```
  # (perhaps you need to escape "+" as "\+",
  # - can you really have a "+" in the URL?)

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/red-widgets-cid-1234+10+5(.*).html [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) %{HTTP_HOST}/american-red-widgets-cid-6789+5%1.html [QSA,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/red-widgets-cid-1234+10(.*).html [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) %{HTTP_HOST}/red-widgets-cid-6789%1.html [QSA,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/red-widgets-cid-1234(.*).html [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) %{HTTP_HOST}/red-widgets-cid-4567%1.html [QSA,L]
```

The main thing is to test for the longest "common" URL first.
`%1` means first regexp expression from last `RewriteCond`.
`$1` means first regexp expression from current `RewriteRule`.

**NB!** if the new URL should be the same for all URLs catch by the RewriteCond you should skip `%1`, that is only necessary if you want e.g. `american-red-widgets-cid-6789+5-1.html` for `red-widgets-cid-1234+10+5-1.html`

Comment: In the RewriteRule statement, do we use %1 or $1 ?  
Also, what if we are also dealing with:  

**Current URLs Example3:**  
www.domain.com/red-widgets-cid-1234+10+5.html  
www.domain.com/red-widgets-cid-1234+10+5-1.html  
www.domain.com/red-widgets-cid-1234+10+5-1-1.html  
  
**Canonical on All Above URLs:**  
www.domain.com/red-widgets-cid-1234+10+5.html  
  
**New URL:**  
www.domain.com/american-red-widgets-cid-6789+5.html  
Can we also use wildcard in the "red-widgets" area of the URL for the RewriteCond rules ? The application only looks at what's after cid.

Comment: I updated my answer, but you should add your new question in your original question, otherwise it's a little bit confusing.